# What is this bug in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to edit and save a javascript file, IntelliJ makes it impossible:

Cannot save C:\Users\dev\joo-web\trunk\joo-admin-web\src\main\webapp\scripts\extjs\examples\tree\treegrid.json.
The file was renamed to treegrid.json_**jb_old_**.
Your changes were written to treegrid.json_**jb_bak_**.

Why has this happened? What is possible to do to fix it?

Comment: Is the file open in another program?

Comment: @vikingsteve No. My colleagues also had this bug and they said that it is MS-Windows that locks the file and they didn't solve it and switched to Apple computers instead.

Comment: What happens if you open the file in notepad, modify it, can you save it? This should eliminate that possibility. Otherwise, what version of IntelliJ are you on?

Comment: @vikingsteve IntelliJ v12. I think it's the app server that locks the file. If I shutdown the app server then I can modify the file as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use Jetty? I encountered with this problem too, and thanks to your reminding I switched to Tomcat7, problem solved :)

Comment: Yes, If I shutdown Jetty then I can edit the file. Thanks for confirming the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Please try turning `Settings | General | Use "safe write"` option off - this should eliminate problems like this (most likely caused by permissions issues)

Comment: I've noticed an improvement after doing this, and the problem seems not to appear at all if I shutdown the application server. So I conclude that it's the app server / operating system that has locked the file and that this is a known issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this with a file - it turned out to be my shell "TCCLE" from JPSoft - was still holding onto the file. I couldn't tell why but I'm guessing it was a recent FFIND search I did.

This probably won't be the case for your file, but you can use the same diagnostic technique: get ProcessExplorer from SysInternals and use the "Find->File Handle or DLL" menu and enter the name of your file to search for. That will tell you which process is locking it.

In my case the file itself was not being held but tcc.exe was locking myfile_jb_old_. 
Killing tcc.exe solved it.